Laravel application experiencing database timeouts when using firstOrNew or firstOrCreate methods in production with large number of records
I'm encountering performance issues with a Laravel application deployed in a production environment. The application is designed to register views for videos, and it utilizes the firstOrNew method to retrieve or create device records for each view. However, regardless of whether the traffic is heavy or moderate, the application encounters persistent database timeouts, particularly when interacting with the devices table, which contains approximately 20 million records. Additionally, there are instances where a single request to the database takes upwards of 30 seconds to complete. It's worth noting that the database in use is MariaDB.
public function store(Request $request){
        // define message for when view is already registered
        $mssg = 'view already exist';

        try{
            // Start database transaction
            // Retry 3 times if first attempt fails (this is done to avoid db deadlock issues)
            DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $mssg) {
                // get request data
                $ip = $request->ip();
                $videoId = $request->input('video_id');
                $hostname = $request->has('embed_source') ? $request->input('embed_source') : NULL;

                // check if view already counted
                if(View::where(['ip' => $ip, 'video_id' => $videoId])->count()) throw new Exception($mssg);

                // Register new view
                // Firstly, retrieve or create device
                $agent = new Agent();
                $position = Location::get($ip);
                $device = Device::firstOrNew(
                    [
                        'type' => $agent->isDesktop() ? 'desktop' : ($agent->isTablet() ? 'tablet' : ($agent->isPhone() ? 'phone' : 'unknown')),
                        'browser' => strtolower($agent->browser()),
                        'country' => $position && $position->countryName ? strtolower($position->countryName) : null,
                        'region' => $position && $position->regionName ? strtolower($position->regionName) : null,
                        'city' => $position && $position->cityName ? strtolower($position->cityName) : null,
                        'hostname' => $hostname,
                    ],
                    [
                        'long' => $position && $position->longitude ? $position->longitude : null,
                        'lat' => $position && $position->latitude ? $position->latitude : null,
                    ]
                );
                $device->save();

                // Secondly, save new view with device ID
                $view = new View();
                $view->video_id = $videoId;
                $view->device_id = $device->id;
                $view->ip = $ip;
                $view->watched_duration = 1;
                $view->save();
                // Lastly, increment views count in videos table
                Video::where('id', $videoId)->increment('total_views');

            }, 3);
            
            return response(['viewed' => true], 200);
            
        }catch(\Throwable $e){
            if($e->getMessage() == $mssg) return response(['message' => $mssg], 200);

            info($e->getMessage(), [
                'title' => 'COULD NOT REGISTER VIEW',
            ]);
            return response(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }

I'm uncertain about the root cause of this issue and how best to resolve it.
I'm seeking guidance on how to optimize the code to improve performance and prevent database timeouts when trying to read from the devices table. Specifically, I'm looking for recommendations on alternative approaches to retrieving or creating device records, optimizing database queries, and scaling the application to handle the current workload efficiently.
Any insights, suggestions, or best practices would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

It is pretty difficult to suggest any optimisation to database queries when we do not know what database queries are executed, what their execution plan is, and what the underlying data structure is.

Here are some (possible) improvements:

Don't use count() to check existence of a record, use exists()

Make a composite unique index for type, browser, country, region, city, hostname columns in database or create a unique hash column and check against hash of these values.

If you added separate indexes for these columns, remove that indexes. This could slow down your write operations.



your question is unclear, are you facing issue while fetching 20 million data or you are trying to insert 20 million data at one go, apart from this what I understand is your one request is taking around 30 sec to respond, which is a lot for any user, for that you can use Jobs/Queue in laravel so that what ever data inserting part is happening will happen in backend and your server will also not load too much
